# Safely convert objects to strings without getting unicode errors?

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode

If I have an unknown object X with some method of getting a string representation (`__unicode__`, `__str__`, `__repr__`, etc.).

How can I safely convert that object to a unicode string without ever having to worry about seeing any of those ugly unicode encode/decode errors?

Comment: By using `unknown object` in you program you ask for trouble. I don't know what you mean. Normally you should know the tools you're using. Especially the encoding of incoming data.

Comment: Suppose your unknown object is a bytestring. It has `__str__`, `__repr__` methods (but no `__unicode__`). Without knowing its character encoding, you can't decode it into Unicode text unambiguously and without losing information in the general case. [There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).